# Where can I view a changelog for the sort command

Tags: documentation, coreutils

I need to find `sort`'s version when the `-V` flag was introduced. But I am finding myself some hard time finding the changelog for this command. Where can I view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the version of `sort` which is part of the GNU coreutils, you can find its changelog in any source tarball (available [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/)).

Comment: I don't seem to find what I need. Perhaps I am not looking in the right place, but can you guide me a bit?

Comment: I can't find anything in the changelog either. However, the `-V` flag wasn't there in version 5.92, so it was introduced some time after that. Worst case, download the tarballs sequentially and check the man page for `sort` (`man man/sort.1`) until you see `-V`.

Comment: Yes, that's the version I have and does not have the flag. But I need something to be sure, as I need to check `sort`'s version and conditionally add the `-V` flag to it. Shouldn't there exist some kind of command changelog or something?

Comment: If you want to know whether a particular implementation of `sort` has the `-V` flag, just try to run `sort` with it and see whether or not it fails. This will be more reliable than relying on version numbers, since version numbers will fail on non-GNU implémentations.

Comment: Alright...will do this then :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way:

```
sort -V /dev/null || { echo 'drats' >&2; exit 1; }
```

For the record, coreutils sort v7.0 (2008-10-05) has the required functionality:
http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD

Comment: This command returns nothing on my machine (Debian wheezy).

Comment: Nothing for me also...