# Select and sort IP address keeping the whole line

Tags: linux, bash, sort

So I need to sort the IP Addresses and then sort my line by them.

I can sort IP addres in a file by using : `sort -n -t . -k1,1 -k2,2 -k 3,3 -k4,4`

If my file looks like :

```
    add method1 a.b.c.d other thing
    add method2 e.f.g.h other thing2
    add method2 a.b.c.d other thing2
    add method5 j.k.l.m other thing5
    add method3 a.b.c.d other thing3
    add method1 e.f.g.h other thing2
```

But in this case, field 1 will be :

```
    add method1 a
    add method2 e
    add method2 a
    add method5 j
    add method3 a
    add method1 e
```

And field 4 will be :

```
    d other thing
    h other thing2
    d other thing2
    m other thing5
    d other thing3
    h other thing2
```

How and What tools should I use to sort my IP addresses and then sort my lines by them.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Example modfied. There is several line with the same IP address but with different text and in a random order.

Comment: [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) would tell you about the `-k` flag

Comment: I understand -k allow me to select start field and stop field with optionnal character. The method I know to sort the IP field will only keep the IP and not the entire line. What I want to do is select the IP field, sort them and print the line by this order.

Comment: in your example field one is `add method1 a` (for first record).

Comment: Yes I know, I edit the file forgetting  this part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This script copies the ip address from field 3 using awk to the
start of the line with a "%" separator, then does the sort
on the ip address now in the first field, then removes
the added part.

```
awk '{print $3 " % " $0}' |
sort -t. -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 |
sed 's/[^%]*% //'
```

---

If the field with the ip address is not a constant, you can
auto-detect it on each line. Replace the awk above with:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
         if($i~/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)break;
       print $i " % " $0
     }' |
```

Comment: I added a change to cope with the ip field position being variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.That's exactly the kind of trick I was looking for. I will learn about awk then.

Answer (score 16):

Late answer, but it might help someone. If you have a recent version of GNU sort (from [GNU coreutils 7.0](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS?id=v7.0) or later), you can use the [`--version-sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html) (or `-V`) option, which will do the right thing with IPv4 addresses. Assuming input of:

```
add method1 10.1.2.3 other thing
add method2 10.10.20.30 other thing2
add method2 10.1.2.3 other thing2
add method5 10.2.8.9 other thing5
add method3 10.1.2.3 other thing3
add method1 10.10.20.30 other thing2
```

Running this through `sort -k 3 -V` will yield:

```
add method1 10.1.2.3 other thing
add method2 10.1.2.3 other thing2
add method3 10.1.2.3 other thing3
add method5 10.2.8.9 other thing5
add method1 10.10.20.30 other thing2
add method2 10.10.20.30 other thing2
```

Comment: Your answer is quite interesting for IPv4 addresses and I keep it in mind. I keep @meuh anwser since I can handle ipv6 with the same logic.

Comment: This is a great trick! When did the -V option get included in GNU sort?

Comment: Nice one, that's perfect. @ChrisDR see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131486/where-can-i-view-a-changelog-for-the-sort-command `coreutils sort v7.0 (2008-10-05)`

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, make sure you understand the `-t` option (`man sort`: field separator).  The command you wanted to use deals with *plain* ip addresses only.

A quick and dirty solution might be to convert the spaces into dots `.` the file first and then sort (you may want to undo the conversion later, excluding the IP addresses)

```
sed -i.bak 's/ /./g' data.log
sort -n -t . -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 data.log
```

Note that I shifted the indices. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know `-t` is used to modify the filed separator, that's why when you have only IP addresses on the line, it sort them correctly. It seems a little bit complexe to remove the dot from everywhere except those which were already there for exemple if i have other numbers instead of letters on other fileds.